# Fiware Orion NGSI-LD : Support of LanguageMap

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I would like to know weither the LanguageMap functionnality is supported (or will be supported) in the Orion-LD implementation.

The languageMap is presented on the folowing video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ll-t8Vi9i50

The idea is to be able to request an attribute in a specific language. Exemple with the following JSON :
"pitch": {
"type": "Property",
"value": [
{
"language ": "fr",
"article": "Mariage"
},
{
"language": "en",
"article": "Wedding"
},
{
"language": "ru",
"article": "Выставка!"
},
{
"language": "zh",
"article": "展览"
},
{
"language": "ja",
"article": "展覧会"
}
]
},

How to query a specific language article?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback.

Rgds

LC

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will most definitely be supported.
Not the very first item on our Backlog, but yeah, it's **quite** **prioritized**. Third item in a list of hundreds of items ... (right now - the list is somewhat volatile).

It will not be exactly as in your example, please check the [latest published ETSI NGSI-LD spec](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.05.01_60/gs_CIM009v010501p.pdf) to get it right. It's something like this:

```
"pitch": {
  "type": "LanguageProperty",
  "languageMap": {
    "en": "marriage",
    "fr": "mariage",
    "es": "matrimonio",
    ...
  }
}
```

If you create an issue on Orion-LD's [github](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues), you will be  informed as soon as the work begins on this, and I can even send a hint every now and then, before the work actually begins. Hopefully, work will commence on this interesting feature before summer, but I can't really promise anything.

About queries, if I remember correctly, the query will be done simply with

```
?q=pitch==matrimonio&lang=es
```

*(please check the API spec to verify what I just said)*